# Animation issue in safari

Tags: css, animation, safari

I have a done a carousel banner with CSS animation, but it is not work well on iOS that after press home button and open Safari again.

Here is the video what happened.

https://youtu.be/44MJKnxYlos

It is also happen on macOS. I open the web site with Safari, then minimize Safari. Again open the Safari, and the banner become blank.

This is my css code:

```
.banner{
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
     animation: banner 15s ease-in-out infinite;
     -webkit-animation: banner 15s ease-in-out infinite;
     height: 100vh;
     }
    
    @include keyframes(banner){
      0%{
        background-image: url('image1.jpg');
      }
      28%{
        background-image: url('image2.jpg');
      }
      33%{
        background-image: url('image3.jpg');
      }
      61%{
        background-image: url('image4.jpg');
      }
      66%{
        background-image: url('image5.jpg');
      }
      95%{
        background-image: url('image6.jpg');
      }
      100%{
        background-image: url('image7.jpg');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

### I Know What Happened. You Know what **Safari**,IE,Deit are some old browser and they Don't Support New Modern Animations And APIs But Don't Worry I think Most of People Use **Chrome,Edge,Firefox,etc...** which are Modern Browser (Test with them) But if You are still Having Troubles The Problems is in code

> Please Briefly Upload Your Code,i HAVE'T See your Video

---

Or I Would Recommend Not Use these Images For Animation  , Visit [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxC_gFQl918&ab_channel=vishAcademy)
also Visit https://daneden.github.io/animation.css
[Such a Cool thing] [also Visit my Question about animation.css]